# sharp peaks in network usage while streaming video, not while streaming music

Tags: wifi-transfer

I'm watching netflix with the Windows task manager open. The Wi-Fi graph in the performance tab shows ~100% network usage for a second or two and then drops to ~0%. Can someone explain why it's operating on this cycle instead of a steadier constant streaming? When I'm streaming music, there's a large peak before the song and then no usage until the next one.

Comment: Videos are larger and get downloaded in parts.

Comment: @Paul I kinda figured, but if the video is staying in memory, what's the advantage of dl'ing a new chunk every two seconds instead of a mass dl at the beginning or some other interval?

Comment: I imagine it is better for bandwidth management. Lots of people downloading small chunks infrequently is better than massive downloads less often.